# flexible drag/drop with jquery (like this javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to understand how **[this drag/drop javascript example](http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx)** would be done in jquery. I'm guessing the jquery version will be cleaner, more efficient, and easier to understand.

Comment: U must use google before posting here. simply "jquery drag and drop" will give u the first result. check this  http://bit.ly/bAIcEz

Comment: @piemesons, *should* use Google...but any question worth Googling-for, is worth asking here. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i do it w/o using jQuery UI. Assumes you've styled `.draggable` to also be `position: absolute`:

```
var $draggable = null, startX, startY;

$('.draggable').live('mousedown', function(ev) {
    $draggable = $(this);
    var pos = $draggable.position();
    startX = ev.pageX - pos.left;
    startY = ev.pageY - pos.top;
    return false;
});

$(document).bind('mousemove', function(ev) {
    if ($draggable) {
        $draggable.css({ left: ev.pageX - startX, top: ev.pageY - startY});
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).bind('mouseup', function(ev) {
    if ($draggable) {
        $draggable = null;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/). They have a lot of cool stuff, including drag/drop, that's really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this from [Jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ . you can view the source. You'll need to link to jquery and to jquery ui.